# min vs max difference in pandas dataframe by column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below,

```
             40    50    60    
Friday     2.68  2.41  2.02  
Monday     4.07  3.74  3.41  
Thursday   4.94  4.57  4.02  
Tuesday    4.82  4.59  3.98  
Wednesday  2.76  2.68  2.37
```

I want to subtract max - min value from each values on 40 to 90 and then find the min value of key value(60) from the calculation.

like `[{40:[4.94 - 2.68 = 2.26]},{50:[4.59-2.41=2.18]},{60:[4.02-2.02 = 2]}]`
and finally,

`[{40:[2.26]},{50:[2.18]},{60:[2]}]`

```
FinalOutput = 60
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dictionary use dict comprehension:

```
d = {k:[v] for k, v in df.max().sub(df.min()).items()}
print (d)
{'50': [2.1799999999999997], '40': [2.2600000000000002], '60': [1.9999999999999996]}
```

For index of minimal value [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
a = df.max().sub(df.min()).idxmin()
print (a)
60
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.max().sub(df.min()))
40    2.26
50    2.18
60    2.00
dtype: float64
```

Comment: why I am getting error `{df[col]:max(df[col])-min(df[col]) for col in df.columns.tolist()}`

Comment: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
`

Comment: @pyd - I think need `a = {col: df[col].max() - df[col].min() for col in df.columns.tolist()}`

Answer (score 0):

In one calculation, you can use [`numpy.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to index [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html#pandas.DataFrame.columns):

```
A = df.values

res = df.columns[(A.max(0) - A.min(0)).argmin()]  # 60
```

If you need intermediary values, then you can split apart the calculation. Note the argument `0` for `max` and `min` methods ensure that calculations are performed on each column.